# is it possible to use named functions with gspread?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gspread, named

I want to use a function on a cell with gspread, how does it work?

tried this:

```
cell_b2 = worksheet.COUNT(D3,E7).value
```

[the function I want to execute using gspread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNqdo.png)

does not work

Comment: [Lookup custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What does `convert my cells using a named function while reading it with gspread` mean?

Comment: `I want to use a function on a cell with gspread, how does it work?` It can **NOT** be done. We can't suggest a workaround/alternative because you have not described the outcome that you are trying to reach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using built-in spreadsheet functions in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660574/using-built-in-spreadsheet-functions-in-a-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi unfortunately it does not work this way.

In order to use a spreadsheet function (like `COUNT` or `IF` etc) you must update the cell where you want that function using methods like: `update_acell` that will update a single celle with the new content.

Example:

```py
worksheet.update_acell("A1", "=COUNT(D3,E7)")
```

then the result can be seen in the spreadsheet in the worksheet at the cell A1.